# Linking to specific page in PDFs

Tags: android, html, jquery, pdf, href

I am trying to link to a specific page within a PDF.

For desktop the URL works with:

https://www.examsolutions.net/papers/edexcel/gcse/nov17/paper2/paper2QUE.pdf#page=3

It takes you to page three, but does not work on mobile. However if I use jQuery

```
if ($(window).width() < 600) {
   $("a").each(function(){
      var newUrl = $(this).attr('href').replace('page=', 'page');
      $(this).attr('href', newUrl);
    });
}
```

The URL is changed to:

https://www.examsolutions.net/papers/edexcel/gcse/nov17/paper2/paper2QUE.pdf#page3

The removal of the '=' works, but only on iOS from my testing. Is there a solution for Android or is it not possible due to Adobe PDF licensing etc?

There are thousands of links to exam questions to help students so creating individual PDFs is not really an option!

Comment: In Android, which app do you use to open the PDF? browser or other app?

Comment: Hey Raptor. The feedback i'm getting is that it's through the browser as a result of clicking the link on the site.

Comment: for different Android OS versions, the browser used can be different; also, users can download other browser apps such as Opera and Firefox and set them as the default browser as well. I think you have to narrow down the issue first. Also, record the problematic browser version.

Comment: see [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver/link-to-a-specific-page-in-pdf-file/m-p/9181600). Seems that this feature is not reliable, and not all browsers are supported well.